# httpinterceptor test failing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular6

I'm using Angular 6, and I'm writing a unit test to test when an HTTP request gets an error that's not a `401` or a `404`.

When debugging the test in the karma runner, I can get the line of code that says `this.router.navigate(['/genericErrorPage'])` to execute due to the test setup, but I cannot get the test to pass, and I'm not sure why the test if failing since router.navigate( ) was actually called during the test execution.

I have tried spying on the `router` object in the test and the `mockRouter` object in the test, but neither cause the test to pass. When using either spy, I get "FAILED: Expected spy navigate to have been called."

```
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
return next.handle(request).pipe(
  catchError(err => {
    if (err.status !== 404 || err.status !== 401) {
      this.router.navigate(['/genericErrorPage']);
    }
    const error = err.statusText;
    return throwError(error);
  })
);
```

}
}

```
fdescribe('ErrorInterceptor', () => {
  class MockRouter {
  navigate = function() {};
}
let router: Router;
let interceptor: ErrorInterceptor;
const mockRouter: MockRouter = new MockRouter();

beforeEach(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter }
  ]
});

router = TestBed.get(Router);
interceptor = new ErrorInterceptor(router);
});

fit('should use router to navigate to error page on error', done => {
  spyOn(router, 'navigate');
   expect((interceptor as any) instanceof ErrorInterceptor).toBeTruthy();
  const next: any = {
    handle: (request: HttpRequest<any>) => {
    expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
    return Observable.create({ hello: 'world' });
  }
 };
   const req = new HttpRequest<any>('GET', 'http://localhost/any/api');
   interceptor.intercept(req, next).subscribe(obj => done());
  });
});
```

Comment: Your interceptor catches an error emitted by observable, but your observable never emits any error. Your test would be much easier to write if you used the http client test controller.

Answer (score 1):

here is what I ended up doing:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
   constructor(private router: Router) {}

   intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
     return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          if (err.status === 401) {
          }
          if (err.status === 404) {
          } else {
              this.router.navigate(['/genericErrorPage']);
          }

         return throwError(err);
        })
      );
     }
    }


import { ErrorInterceptor } from './error-interceptor';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { mock } from 'ts-mockito/lib/ts-mockito';

import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { EmployeeHomeService } from '../../services/employee/employee-home/employee-home.service';
import { USER_PROFILE_API_LOCATION } from '../../constants';

describe('ErrorInterceptor', () => {
   class MockRouter {
    navigate = function() {};
   }
  let employeeHomeService: EmployeeHomeService; //still need to make this generic/mock in case the EmployeeHomeService changes
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let mockRouter: MockRouter;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
       providers: [
        EmployeeHomeService,
        {
           provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
           useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
           multi: true
        },
         { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter }
       ]
     });
    mockRouter = TestBed.get(Router);
    employeeHomeService = TestBed.get(EmployeeHomeService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
   });

  it('should have router redirect to error page on HTTP 500', done => {
    spyOn(mockRouter, 'navigate');
    employeeHomeService.retrieveEmployee().subscribe(
      res => {
        expect(false).toEqual(true); //should not hit here, but if it does, test will fail
        done();
      },
      err => {
     expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/genericErrorPage']);
         done();
      }
    );

    httpMock.expectOne(USER_PROFILE_API_LOCATION).error(new ErrorEvent('500 
error'), {
       status: 500
     });
     httpMock.verify();
   });
 });



 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { Employee } from '../../../containers/employee/models/employee';
 import { USER_PROFILE_API_LOCATION } from '../../../constants';

 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
 export class EmployeeHomeService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  retrieveEmployee(): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http.get<Employee>(USER_PROFILE_API_LOCATION);
  }
 }
```